# Facebook Graph api wall post not as link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-wall

Using the graph api I can post to a users wall:

```
    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
  @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
  @"http://www.xmaselves.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/gym.png", @"picture",
 [self getTitleText], @"name",
 [self getCaptionText], @"caption",
 [self getFbFormattedDescription], @"description",
 _comment.text, @"message",
 nil];

[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
 parameters:postParams
 HTTPMethod:@"POST" .... etc
```

The problem is this only seems to post on the wall as a link:
[image]
I want the post to appear as normal and not as a 'shared a link' post. How do achieve this with the graph api.

**EDIT**

1. Removing the link paramater and making sure @message is specified will indeed post to the wall.
2. If you remove the link paramater and do not specify message nothing is posted and no error is returned!
3. In the screenshot 'asdadasd' would be the user entered message but this is optional! So if they don't enter a message the post wont be displayed! As a matter of fact this same behaviour is exhibited by the 'Feed dialogue' api.

So all posts need to have a message? or posted as a link? This doesn't seem right.

Comment: _“want the post to appear as normal and not as a 'shared a link' post. How do achieve this with the graph api.”_ – only by not having  `link` parameter in there at all.

Comment: I had tried this before and nothing was posted at all. Trying it again though yields some strange results, i will update the question.

Comment: _“So all posts need to have a message? or posted as a link? This doesn't seem right.”_ – _without_ a message and _without_ a link – what’s there _left_ to be posted? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: There are a few paramaters, 'name', 'title', 'description' and 'caption' is all I require. 'message' is just something the user can enter according to the api. I am posting to a users facebook wall from my iphone app.

Comment: `message`_or_ `link`, at least _one_ of those _is_ required – otherwise you can not make a feed post. The other parameters you mentioned, `name`, `caption`, `description` can _only_ be used if a `link` is given as well.

Comment: I am seeing the same behaviour with fbs feed dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/. Message is optional as it should be but if you don't enter it the post doesn't appear on the wall.

Comment: "message_or_ link, at least one of those is required" it is not required in fbs own feed dialog! Then again that thing is full of bugs.

Comment: "name, caption, description can only be used if a link" they are showing up fine if i don't specify a link but instead specify a message.

Comment: That’s news to me, and contradicts what the docs say. Maybe worth filing a bug report.

Comment: hmm this is possibly one of the worst apis I have ever used, full of bugs, bad docs and about 3 or 4 legacy apis with functionality that is harder to reproduce in the current api.

Comment: "and contradicts what the docs say" I didn't see it mentioned in the docs, where abouts does it say that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16048/discussion-between-imran-and-cbroe)